# How to fix `listen EACCES: permission denied` on any port

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, node.js, npm

Has anyone experienced something liked this with node:

I was running `Angular`, my Windows crashed and restarted and now when I try `ng serve` I'm getting:

```
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:4200
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1253:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1318:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1451:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:61:10)
```

I also tried `ng serve --port 4201`

Same result.

NOTE: Before *Windows* restarted I was running the app in `WSL`. After, I tried `WSL` and `Powershell`.

Update: It is even happening with a new project.

Comment: Try to uninstall and reinstall the whole WSL distro and redo all the steps. Or redo the steps in a newer distro install. Does this also occurs?

Comment: I'll try that. 
Right now, I already reinstalled node on Windows and check if the port was being used, it is not.
Thanks for the advice, let you know if it worked.

Comment: I uninstall `Ubuntu` and installed `Debian` and the problem continues

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One Windows restart isn't enough, I restarted twice and the problem is gone.

Sorry, I don't have anything more technical.

Except:
1: Try not to develop on WSL from a Windows folder.

Comment: You saved my day by restarting  windows twice.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped you. It is not a pretty answer, but it is not a pretty problem neither.

Comment: This has also helped me with my EACCES that wasn't related to node (and I don't even think it was WSL related, but I use WSL). When in doubt try turning it off and on again twice.

Comment: it fixed my issue (happened after i did windows updates)

Comment: This fixed my issue also

Comment: Don't know how but it worked.

Comment: This was one of stupidest solutions I've ever heard, yet it worked! many thanks

Comment: The "double-restart" is probably because Windows did not stopped the first time because of the "fast startup" feature being enabled by default. More details here: https://www.howtogeek.com/349114/shutting-down-doesnt-fully-shut-down-windows-10-but-restarting-it-does/ Restarting twice did a real shutdown IMO.

Comment: A process is running. check you port use taskkill

Comment: I used to fix this issue restarting Windows, but it would come back eventually. The ``netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`` is great for diagnosis, and eventually the bunch of netsh dynamic tcp commands fixed it.

Answer (score 37):

In my case the error appears because the port used belong to reserved ports for Hyper-V.

This port range changes when I restart my computer, so sometimes I get the error sometimes no.

To check reserved ports by windows you can use(cmd/powershell):

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

The issue is described in: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5514

General workround (in comment 554587817): https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171#issuecomment-554587817

Fast workround: choose a port that not belong to reserved ranges

Comment: Aha! This might be the problem for me too. 3000 is in that range. I wish there was a better error than access denied, since we tend to associate that with 'port in use', not 'port reserved'.

Answer (score 14):

kudos to @fambrosi to find the thread and https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171#issuecomment-788808021. Here is the command to solve this annoying issue.

```
net stop winnat
netsh int ipv4 set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384
netsh int ipv6 set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384
net start winnat
```

Comment: Just stopping and restarting worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Similar answer from <[Node.js EACCES error when listening on most ports](//stackoverflow.com/a/65698209)> and article
https://medium.com/@Bartleby/ports-are-not-available-listen-tcp-0-0-0-0-3000-165892441b9d

Comment: this actually worked for me

Answer (score 4):

For me it was that node is listening on the wrong network interface.

After using docker it was using the docker network interface as primary.

Disabling the network interface to force node to use the correct interface did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I also Faced the same issue while trying `ng serve` command on the terminal.

```bat
an unhandled exception occurred: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:4200
see "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-At4Tad\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Solution: Simply modify the command as

```bat
ng serve --port 4401
```

Comment: C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\AngularExample>ng serve --port 4401
10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4401/webpack-dev-server/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4401, open your browser on http://localhost:4401/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Restart was not enough! The only way to solve the problem is by the following:

You have to kill the service which run at that port.

At cmd, run as admin, then type :

```
netstat -aon | find /i "listening"
```

Then you will get a list with the active service, search for the port that is running at 4200 and use the process id which is the last column to kill it by:

```
taskkill /F /PID 2652
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the growing list of things that might be the issue: I was using ExpressVPN on my computer, this somehow interfered with binding any localhost port. Uninstalling + restarting fixed the issue for me!

Comment: Indeed. To fix the issue: disconnect VPN Express & reconnect again.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me, triggered by running Vue dev server on port `3000`. In my case, I wanted to browse to `localhost:3000` via a custom host-mapped local domain name (e.g. `mysite.dev`) instead, so I incorrectly set my local Apache configuration to listen on `0.0.0.0:3000` and defined `<VirtualHost *:3000>`.  So Apache was already using the port.

Answer (score 0):

I recently updated my docker to the latest version and my angular application started giving me this error. After investigating I found that port 4200 (the default port which angular applications use) is occupied by other applications.

I ran the application with a different port and solved the problem.

```
ng serve --port 4000
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above answers don't fix your issue, your port could be bound via netsh. You can use the following command to see if your port proxies information to elsewhere; I had bound port 3000 to another ip and received this error as a result.

```
netsh interface portproxy show all
```

If you do have the port bound, you can remove the port binding with:

```
netsh interface portproxy listenport=(your port) listenaddress=(ip address)
```